# Built Vue SPA not working when using "publicPath"

Tags: express, vue.js

I set a public path in `vue.config.js` like

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/subpath'
};
```

it works fine when I start the devlopment server with `npm run serve` (`vue-cli-service serve`). The app becomes available at `localhost:8080/subpath` which is exactly what I want. It uses `vue-router` and at least in development it seems to work perfekt with the `/subpath` as publicPath.

### Problem

I am using Express to serve the app files. Running `npm run build` the app will be built and stored to `./dist` folder (default output folder).

```js
// simplified server.js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.sendfile('./dist/index.html');
});
```

After starting my express server and visiting my browser at `localhost:<port>/subpath` or `localhost:<port>` it can't find the necessary files.

```
// EXAMPLE FROM BROWSER CONSOLE
GET http://localhost:5050/subpath/js/app.6c6daa90.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Which somehow looks obvious to me but **I don't know how to set the express server correctly to respect the publicPath setting** . Maybe there is a different approach ?

### Attempt #1

I made a little change in my express server.js

```js
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

/* NEW */
app.use('/subpath', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
```

This way it should serve the static files from the `/dist` folder when requested with `/subpath/app.js`

#### Result

From Browser console when requesting `localhost:<port>/subpath` or `localhost:<port>`

```
Refused to load the font 'data:application/font-woff2;base64,<omitted>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:5050/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with express.static and this combination seems to work for me

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const app     = express();

app.use(history());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use('/subpath', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

const listener = app.listen(5050, () => {
  console.log(`Open http://localhost:${port} in your browser`);
});
```

Sidenote : Adding `connect-history-api-fallback` was not required to solve the initial problem but is required for `vue-router` to work properly when in history mode.